# How to use two IEnumerable Model in one view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to use two models in one View. Here is my code for model:

Model "Announce"

```
public partial class Announce
{
    public int No { get; set; }
    public string Announce_Subject { get; set; }
    public string Announce_Context { get; set; }
    public string Announce_Author { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Announce_Date { get; set; }
}
```

Model Message

```
public partial class Message
{
    public int MessageId { get; set; }
    public string MessageTo { get; set; }
    public string MessageFrom { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Model Total for two models

```
public class Total
{
    public IEnumerable<Announce> Announce1 { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Message> Message { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
@model DemoEmployee.Total

@foreach (var item in Model.Announce1)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Announce_Subject, "Details", "Announces", new { id = item.No }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Announce_Author)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Announce_Date)
        </td>
    </tr>
}


@foreach (var item in Model.Message)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MessageFrom)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Text, "Details", new { id = item.MessageId })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.MessageId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Indexcontroller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Announce.ToList());
}
```

I don't know what is my problem. I got this error:

> "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DemoEmployee.Announce]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[DemoEmployee.Total]"

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined `@model DemoEmployee.Total` in your view, you need to pass object of `Total` in `return View()`.

Pass object of `DemoEmployee.Total` into `View(...)` not List of `Announce`. Update your `return` statement as below.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new DemoEmployee.Total() { Announce1 = db.Announce.ToList(), Message = new List<Message>() });
}
```